# Логирование выводов командлетов PowerShell

Tags: логирование, powershell

Подскажите как произвести запись в файл выводимой в консоли информации от следующего командлета.

```
Remove-Item -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода комманды в файл вам необходимо использовать `4>&1` - перенаправляет логирование комманд, в то же место что и стандартный вывод

Ваш вариант:

```
Remove-Item -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file с:\log\log.txt -Append
```

---

Детальный вывод в лог со своими опциями:

```
$Path = "C:\sss" 
get-item $Path | foreach {
    $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose 4>&1
    if (Test-Path $_){
        "Fail $_"
    }
    else{
        "Success delete $_"
    } 

} | out-file с:\log\log.txt -Append
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! То, что нужно было.

Comment: @anst-foto, тогда вам нужно отметить принятие ответа, поставив слева от него галочку, пожалуйста)